# 訓練データとして用いるため、英語で記された景気についてのアンケート調査のデータを入手したい

Tags: 機械学習

プログラミングについての質問とは少しずれているかと思うのですが、ご了承ください。

日本では内閣府が公開している景気ウォッチャー調査といった景気に敏感な人たちを対象とした景気に対する評価（５段階）とその理由のアンケートのファイルがあります。
このアンケートのアメリカ版のようなファイルが欲しいです。つまり、景気に対する評価とその理由が英語で記載されているようなファイルです。

このファイルの用途は、評価を訓練データ教師ラベルとし、その理由を訓練データとしてポジネガ判定の教師データと考えています。

このようなファイルが公開されているサイトを教えてくださいませんか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

理想は以上のように評価とその理由が英語で記載してあるCSVファイル等です。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のあたりが該当すると思われます。
教師データとして使えるかどうかは分かりませんが。

[The Conference Board](https://www.conference-board.org/)から有料のようですが
概要解説：[What is the BCI Database and Internet Service?](https://www.conference-board.org/data/bci/index.cfm?id=2156)  
元データリンク：[Links to Online Sources of U.S. BCI Data](https://www.conference-board.org/data/bci/index.cfm?id=2158)

要約？：[Global Business Cycle Indicators](https://www.conference-board.org/data/bcicountry.cfm?cid=1)

月次に解説：[Economics Watch Reports|All Publications](https://www.conference-board.org/publications/publicationlistall.cfm?sort=type&jumpto=Economics%20Watch%20Reports)
最新刊？：[The Conference Board Economics Watch® Economic Series Report](https://www.conference-board.org/publications/publicationdetail.cfm?publicationid=8191)

[American Institute for Economic Research](https://www.aier.org/)から  
[Business Conditions Monthly](https://www.aier.org/bcm)
[Business-Cycle Conditions](https://www.aier.org/research/business-cycle-conditions)

[Economic Cycle Research Institute](https://www.businesscycle.com/home)から  
[Monitoring Business Cycles Today](https://www.businesscycle.com/business_cycles/monitoring_business_cycles_today)

根拠は日本の総務省の少し古い資料の一部と思われる、これですね。
[5.2 諸外国等における景気動向指標](http://www.soumu.go.jp/main_sosiki/singi/toukei/nenpou/chousa/chousa_1503/chousa_1503_5b.pdf)

> 5.2.1 米国における主要な景気動向指標
>    　本項では、米国における代表的な景気動向指標について以下の 3 つについて紹介する。
>    　景気循環指標(Business Cycle Indicators：BCI) 
>    　景気循環状況指標(Business-Cycle Conditions Indicators)
>    　米国週次先行指数(U.S. Weekly Leading Index)

他にはリンクだけで、しかも古いと思われますが、こんなのもあります。
[米国経済統計指標(U.S. economic indicators)](http://www1.odn.ne.jp/keizai/America.htm)
[経済統計｜About THE USA｜アメリカンセンターJAPAN](https://americancenterjapan.com/aboutusa/business/219/)

あとは、米国株式投資をサポートしている証券会社/銀行や投資顧問会社、個人ブログ等を探してみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。該当の資料があるか探してみます。